# Can't move invaders correctly in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to make an Invader game in SpriteKit in Swift with this tutorial:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/1167-how-to-make-a-game-like-space-invaders-with-spritekit-and-swift-part-1

I finished part1 and part2. But the invaders moving is still strange. When the invaders reached the right edge of screen, only one invader go to down line and move left. The others just move to left.

How can I solve it?

[image: bug]

```
enum InvaderMovementDirection {
        case right
        case left
        case downThenRight
        case downThenLeft
        case none
    }

func moveInvaders(forUpdate currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

        if (currentTime - timeOfLastMove < timePerMove) {
            return
        }

        enumerateChildNodes(withName: InvaderType.name) { node, stop in

            switch self.invaderMovementDirection {
            case .right:
                node.position = CGPoint(x: node.position.x + 10, y: node.position.y)
            case .left:
                node.position = CGPoint(x: node.position.x - 10, y: node.position.y)
            case .downThenLeft, .downThenRight:
                node.position = CGPoint(x: node.position.x, y: node.position.y - 10)
            case .none:
                break
            }

            self.timeOfLastMove = currentTime
            self.determineInvaderMovementDirection()

        }
    }


func determineInvaderMovementDirection() {

        var proposedMovementDirection: InvaderMovementDirection = invaderMovementDirection

        enumerateChildNodes(withName: InvaderType.name) { node, stop in

            switch self.invaderMovementDirection {
            case .right:
                if (node.frame.maxX >= node.scene!.size.width - 1.0) {

                    proposedMovementDirection = .downThenLeft
                    self.adjustInvaderMovement(to: self.timePerMove * 0.8)
                    stop.pointee = true
                }
            case .left:

                if (node.frame.minX <= 1.0) {
                    proposedMovementDirection = .downThenRight
                    self.adjustInvaderMovement(to: self.timePerMove * 0.8)
                    stop.pointee = true
                }

            case .downThenLeft:
                proposedMovementDirection = .left
                stop.pointee = true

            case .downThenRight:
                proposedMovementDirection = .right
                stop.pointee = true

            default:
                break
            }

        }

        if (proposedMovementDirection != invaderMovementDirection) {
            invaderMovementDirection = proposedMovementDirection
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to move these lines:

```
        self.timeOfLastMove = currentTime
        self.determineInvaderMovementDirection()
```

to be outside the loop created by:

```
enumerateChildNodes(withName: InvaderType.name)
```

in `func moveInvaders(forUpdatefunc moveInvaders(forUpdate`.

You can do this by simply moving them after the '}'.

I think what's happening is that you are moving one invader and then changing `invaderMovementDirection` to `proposedMovementDirection`, whereas you should be changing changing `invaderMovementDirection` only after ALL the invaders have moved.

So they are moving `.right`, they hit the wall and you process the first invader. You move it and then call `determineInvaderMovementDirection` which sets the proposed direction to `.downThenLeft`. At the end of `determineInvaderMovementDirection` you set the invaders' direction to `.downThenLeft` from `proposedMovementDirection`.

When you process the next invader, it's direction is (incorrectly) set as `.downThenLeft`. so you move it down then left, call `determineInvaderMovementDirection` which sets the invaders' direction to `.left` which is used to process all the other invaders.

Comment: Thank you for your description! I understood what was the problem and it worked well!